# BizTalk Create Message in BRE Rule

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

In an orchestration I notice that if I right-click in a construct message shape and select "Insert Shape" then three options are enabled:

1. Transform
2. Message Assignment
3. Call Rules

[image]

I would like to use the Call Rules option, have the rule populate a newly constructed message. Unfortunately, when I select this, I get the message "A Construct statement can only contain Message Assignment and Transform shapes".

Does anyone know if it possible to have a message populated in a BRE rule?

Comment: Can you post the logic BRE Rule that you are trying to call. How are you creating a message in your BRE Rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the construct shape isn’t required. I guess a copy of the message that’s passed into the rule gets created implicitly.

Comment: That is correct the CallRules shape does not need a Construct shape, it also bends the other rule about the message being immutable as it can update the message contents.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your own answer as the answer ;-)

Comment: Thanks @Dijkgraaf - I often do forget because not allowed to mark right away

Comment: ps I've started using the BRE Pipeline Framework for my current project - it is very impressive. Johann must have spent many many hours developing it. Good to know it's being maintained on github and it seems to work fine with BTS2016 FP3 CU5 - any gotchas with this version of BTS that I should be aware of?

Comment: Yes, one gotcha with BRE and that version if you use the Create SSO Ticket action.  See https://www.connected-pawns.com/2018/10/26/biztalk_2016_microsoft_biztalk_interop_ssoclient/